# EF7 RC2 linq select not include newly added record

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

I have a very quick question. When selecting a record in EF 7 RC2, it doesn't seems to include the newly added record.

Here is my code:

```
public tblCategory AddOrUpdateCat(ref DbLocal ef, int catId, string catName, int catType)
{
    tblCategory db = ef.tblCategories.FirstOrDefault(rec => (rec.CatId == catId));
    if (db == null)
    {
        db = new tblCategory();
        db.CatId = catId;
        ef.tblCategories.Add(db);
    }
    db.Name = catName;
    db.CatType = catType;
    ef.SaveChanges();
    return db;
}
```

The second time calling the function with the same **CatId** throws exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
>
> Additional information: The instance of entity type 'tblCategory' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique

This is because the 2nd time, calling `ef.tblCategories.FirstOrDefault(rec => (rec.CatId == catId))` with the same Id will not retrieve the newly added record.

This behavior is different than in RC1. Any idea how to make it so it behaves like in RC1?

Thanks!

Comment: Who says that RC1 behaved correctly? And why do you still use EF7 (Core) RC2 anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `tblCategory db = ef.tblCategories.FirstOrDefault(rec => (rec.CatId == catId));` or if `catId` is the primary key, then `tblCategory db = ef.tblCategories.Find(catId);`

assuming `ef` is your `DbContext`

Comment: yes, I forgot to put in ef. But it still doesn't work. It will not find the CatId until it saved to database. It was working on EF 7 RC1.

Comment: @Sam I cannot reproduce this issue. Please provide a simple reproducible code sample. You could upload your code project and post link here.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT - I have rolled back to EF - RC1 as I couldn't figured out how to fix this problem. It turned out the data wasn't saved to database. So far, I found that if I untick the **Compile with .NET Native tool chain**, it works (ie. the data is saved). But I am too afraid to give the updated version to my customers without going through each of the saving module to make sure the data is saved properly. So, I rolled back to RC1. I am quite busy at the moment, when I am free, I will try to subset my code and post it here.

Comment: @Sam It's ok. Thank you.